# Assign values to struct members contained in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, structure

I have an array of structs

```
struct SerialNumberData* serialNumberArrayTest
```

and my struct is defined as

```
struct SerialNumberData
{
  const char* serialNumber;
  const char* serialNumberPos;
};
```

What im tryng to do is assign values to the members of the structs and then add the structs to the array. I enter a loop where the values are assigned to each struct and then passed along to the array.

```
for(int i=0; i<numArrays;i++){  
    std::string serial = "serialNumberArray";
    oss << i;
    serial += oss.str();
    std::string readLine =  "Some value" + serial;
    size_t pos = 0;
    std::string token = "Some other value" + serial;

    serialNumberArrayTest[i].serialNumber = token.c_str();
    serialNumberArrayTest[i].serialNumberPos = readLine.c_str();
    //..Logger writes the values to an external log file
    oss.str("");
    oss.clear();
}
```

The problem is that the values of the last struct are being saved to the values of all the structs contained in the array. The logger writes the correct values in the log file but if I also log again after the for loop, all values are overwritten with the last one.

I have tried a number of things too many to recount at this point, even had a go at vectors but to no succes. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are storing pointers to locals (`token` and `readLine`) in the structs. These locals disappear after the loop and may get overwritten within the loop too. Replace `const char*` with `std::string` in your struct and use `std::vector` or `std::array` to store the array of structs. It will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: @crayzeewulf `std::string` is most probably the better choice.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Especially since he's using C++, I can't think of a good reason not to use the `std::string`.

Comment: I cant replace const char* for std::string because this code is part of a legacy code. Shouldn't the values be stored and written with each pass of the for loop?

Comment: @DavidA Do you understand how the legacy code works? Who manages the lifetime of the objects these pointers point to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
serialNumberArrayTest[i].serialNumber = token.c_str();
serialNumberArrayTest[i].serialNumberPos = readLine.c_str();
```

You're storing pointers to temporaries here. Don't do that. Decide who manages the lifetime of the memory and implement that sensibly. If the struct manages the lifetime of its own data, use:

```
serialNumberArrayTest[i].serialNumber = strdup (token.c_str());
serialNumberArrayTest[i].serialNumberPos = strdup (readLine.c_str());
```